# Python receiving a KeyError: 0

Tags: python, runtime-error

New to Python.  I am receiving an error and not sure how to fix it.  AS you an see that I am using soem global variables in the function and initialized the dict to {} at the beginning of the program.

```
def bin_criticality():
    global gbv_bin_criticality, gbv_bin_element_ids, gbv_element_criticality
    gbv_bin_criticality = {}
    for (lv_key, lv_value) in gbv_bin_element_ids.items():
        print (lv_key, lv_value)
        lv_coil_ids = lv_value.split(',')
        for coil_id in lv_coil_ids:
            gbv_bin_criticality[lv_key] += int(gbv_element_criticality[coil_id])
    return()
```

----Error

```
line 112, in bin_criticality
    gbv_bin_criticality[lv_key] += int(gbv_element_criticality[coil_id])
KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gbv_bin_criticality` is an empty dictionary `{}` at the start of the function, so the first time you try:

```
gbv_bin_criticality[lv_key] += int(gbv_element_criticality[coil_id])
```

for a given value of `lv_key` it doesn't yet exist as a key in the dictionary, hence `KeyError`.

You have three options, either check first ([LBYL](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-lbyl)):

```
if lv_key not in gbv_bin_criticality:
     gbv_bin_criticality[lv_key] = 0
gbv_bin_criticality[lv_key] += int(gbv_element_criticality[coil_id])
```

`try` and fail gracefully ([EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-eafp)):

```
try:
    gbv_bin_criticality[lv_key] += int(gbv_element_criticality[coil_id])
except KeyError:
    gbv_bin_criticality[lv_key] = int(gbv_element_criticality[coil_id])
```

or use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), which will automatically handle the missing key, instead of the vanilla `dict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

gbv_bin_criticality = defaultdict(int)
...
gbv_bin_criticality[lv_key] += int(gbv_element_criticality[coil_id])
```

Also, I would ditch the `global`s - make `gbv_bin_element_ids` and `gbv_element_criticality` arguments to the function and `return gbv_bin_criticality` at the end.